# upload file using FormData and post query

Tags: javascript, upload, multipartform-data, fetch-api

I' m trying to upload file on server, sending post query, like this:

```
const files = [...e.dataTransfer.files];
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('taskId', taskId);
    data.append('file', files[0]);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    fetch(`${URL}file`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: data,
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

But I have an error:
statusCode: 400, message: 'Multipart: Boundary not found', error: 'Bad Request'
Swagger documentation: https://prompt-twig-production.up.railway.app/docs/static/index.html#/Tasks/TasksController_create
How to fix my query? What is wrong?

I tried to change headers (remove content-type), but it seems to me, that everything looks correct. I don't know, where is a mistake.